# Android Emulator Genymotion custom resolution and DPI

Tags: android-emulator, genymotion

I start using genynotion emulator , and i am able to create custom size device using Device setting , but when it comes to give custom dpi their is drop down box of predefine dpi is their is any way  to provide custom DPI value to genymotion other than drop down box?

Answer (score 2):

For change DPI you can use ADB shell:

```
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
cat /system/build.prop | grep ro.sf.lcd_density
```

When line is found, it's current DPI and use command below for change it:

```
sed -i 's/^ro.sf.lcd_density=.*/ro.sf.lcd_density=YOUR_DPI/g' /system/build.prop
```

when nothing found, append line to end of file:

```
echo ro.sf.lcd_density=YOUR_DPI >> /system/build.prop
```

Comment: Also we need to reboot the emulator at the end.